# On Iphone Safari browser, the whole page jumps when typing inside a textbox?

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios, css

When I first focus on the textbox, the page jumps up.

Then, when I push keys to type, the page keeps jumping up and down.

It works fine in Android Browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the HEAD of HTML

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
```